# error loading csv into hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to load a tab delimited file into a table in hive, and I want to skip the first row because it contains column names.  I'm trying to run the code below, but I'm getting the error below.  Does anyone see what the issue is?

```
Code:

set hive.exec.compress.output=false;
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;



-- region to state mapping
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StateRegion;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE StateRegion (Zip_Code int,
                                       Place_Name string,
                                       State string,
                                       State_Abbreviate string,
                                       County string,
                                       Latitude float,
                                       Longitude float,
                                       ZIP_CD int,
                                       District_NM string,
                                       Region_NM string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'StateRegion'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE StateRegion;

--test Export
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY './StateRegionTest/'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
select * from StateRegion;


Error:

FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'STORED' 'AS' 'TEXTFILE'
```

Comment: you have an extra `;` before `stored as ..`

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala  thanks for getting back to me so quickly.  When I tried running it before without the semicolon it threw an error about not recognizing the ')' right before STORED

Comment: `tblProperties()` goes after `stored as..`